# How to retrieve the pop up message text using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape filling a form and submitting it. Filling and submitting works fine but I am interested in the pop message returned. So far I am not able to receive the message output. This is my code using Selenium Python.

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


postnummer = [42435, 42448]
street_name =["Bredfjällsgatan", "Fjällviolen"]
street_number = [12, 7]


inputPost = '//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/a/form/input[1]'
inputStreet = '//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/a/form/input[2]'
inputNumber = '//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/a/form/input[3]'

submitButton = '//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/a/form/span[4]'

result = '//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/p/text()[1]'


def sleep():
    time.sleep(3)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get("https://www.framtidensbredband.se/")
browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputPost).send_keys(postnummer[0])
browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputStreet).send_keys(street_name[0])
browser.find_element_by_xpath(inputNumber).send_keys(street_number[0])
sleep()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(submitButton).click()

#print(browser.find_element_by_xpath(result))

sleep()
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath(result))
sleep()
browser.back()
sleep()

browser.quit()
```

The website being scraped is https://www.framtidensbredband.se/

Comment: I believe "result" should target the <iframe> or <frame> tag.  The driver has to switch to it in order to retrieve it's contents.

Comment: Exactly. I might be doing it wrong, though. browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath(result))´´´

Comment: you change frame but you do not take action why are you trying to change frame, do you want to print or do you want to click

Comment: I was able to get the text by simply `print(browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".alertbox .message").text)`. Try that just after you submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to `text`

1- you need to select the element as `text`

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='message']").text
print(elem)
```

2- you need to call the element as `text`

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='message']")
print(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the *pop up* message output you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.framtidensbredband.se/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='postCode']"))).send_keys("42435")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='street']").send_keys("Bredfjällsgatan")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='streetNumber']").send_keys("12")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='banner-button submit-button']").click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='alertbox']//p"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Från och med 2020-12-31 kan du bli kund i det öppna bredbandsnätet. För att hitta och förbeställa tjänster gå in under Tjänster.
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: framtidensbredband]